# Trying to write to a file from a script. Hitting unexpected permission issues

Tags: bash, permissions

I am trying to write a script to edit systemd files.

On the CLI I can use the command:

```
sudo systemctl edit test.service
```

That opens a text editor, I make the changes and save no problems.

In a bash script I am trying to use the command:

```
sudo cat > /etc/systemd/system/test.service.d/override.conf <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add ap0 type __ap
EOF
```

It doesn't work because I don't have the right permissions.

I can then run the command:

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/test.service.d/override.conf
```

and that works.

If I then run again:

```
sudo cat > /etc/systemd/system/test.service.d/override.conf <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add ap0 type __ap
EOF
```

It also fails on permissions.

As far as I can see, this seems to be an issue with the:

```
sudo cat > somefile << EOF
some file text
EOF
```

command sequence.  sudo should break through any permission issues, but doesn't in this case.

Is there a solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really Pi specific, but there is a solution; viz do all your work on a temporary file. Following is an example I have used.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to customise ssmtp
# 2017-08-12

# copy sed script to a temporary file
cat << EOF > /tmp/sedscr
/^\s*index/s/index/index index.php/
/^\s*location \//,/^\s*}/ {
/^\s*location \//,/^\s*}/s/ =404/ \/index.php\?\$args =404/
}
/location ~ \\\\.php/i\\
    # insert from Derek Molloy. “Exploring Raspberry Pi.”\\
    location ~ \\\.php$ {\\
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;\\
       fastcgi_index index.php;\\
       include fastcgi_params;\\
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root/\$fastcgi_script_name;\\
    }

EOF

CONFIG_FILE='/etc/nginx/sites-available/default'

# Check/create Backup Config File
if [ ! -e $CONFIG_FILE.orig ]; then
    sudo cp $CONFIG_FILE $CONFIG_FILE.orig
fi

sed -f /tmp/sedscr $CONFIG_FILE >/tmp/nginx_sites
# sed -f /tmp/sedscr $CONFIG_FILE

# copy modified files from /tmp
sudo cp /tmp/nginx_sites $CONFIG_FILE
```

Comment: I haven't seen that approach in any other answers but it looks like a good option.  I can create the file I want in the ~ dir and then sudo mv it to where it needs to be.

Comment: That does mean I need to chown and chmod the final file but the code is easy to read.

Comment: @dazz it is difficult to generalise. Every time I modify a system file I make a backup (which is good practice) and it is much easier to test/verify on a copy, but what you have to do after depends on the files. The example I posted was one of a set of scripts I developed to configure a fresh install to my preferred settings - useful when going from Jessie to Stretch. This is not that uncommon - the book by Derek Molloy mentioned has similar examples. Unfortunately developing/testing these scripts can be time consuming and `sed` does take quite a bit of learning.

Answer (score 2):

OK
I found this answer:

All redirections (including >) are applied before executing the actual command. In other words, your shell first tries to open /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini for writing using your account, then runs a completely useless sudo cat.

here:
[Redirection](https://superuser.com/questions/340074/bash-permission-denied-issue-when-trying-to-append-to-eof)

EDIT

Based on @Milliways answer, I have applied the following to a script I have written.  This code creates a file in the home folder, then moves it to the required folder. Ownership and permissions are set to suit.

```
#Create the file in the home dir
cat > ~/12-ap0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=ap0
[Network]
Address="$ap0_IP"
DHCPServer=yes
IPForward=no
EOF
#move it to where it needs to be
sudo mv ~/12-ap0.network /etc/systemd/network/12-ap0.network
#set the ownership and permissions
sudo chown root:root /etc/systemd/network/12-ap0.network
sudo chmod 777 /etc/systemd/network/12-ap0.network
```

This adds just one extra line (mv ...) to the code.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear you should write the solution into your answer instead of linking to it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/systemd/system/test.service.d/override.conf <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add ap0 type __ap
EOF'
```

Consider the two **`'`** character. Because of formating I couldn't put this in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because redirections are not handled by the command (`sudo cat` in your case), but by the shell running your script. Since the shell is not being run as root, it doesn't have the permissions to open the file.

A typical workaround is

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/test.service.d/override.conf > /dev/null <<EOF
your text
EOF
```

The difference is that `tee` doesn't rely on redirections but actually opens the file by name.